# What does the "0" mean in MongoDB's BinData(0, "e8MEnzZoFyMmD7WSHdNrFJyEk8M=")?

Tags: mongodb, base64, bson

The MongoDB shell prints binary data as a Base64-encoded string wrapped in what looks like a function call:

```
"_id" : BinData(0,"e8MEnzZoFyMmD7WSHdNrFJyEk8M=")
```

What does the "0" mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#binary

The BSON BinData datatype is represented via class BinData in the shell. Run `help misc` for more information.

```
> new BinData(2, "1234")
BinData(2,"1234")
```

from the shell

```
help misc
b = new BinData(subtype,base64str)  create a BSON BinData value
```

The `0` in your case is the BSON subtype

http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

```
binary  ::=   int32 subtype (byte*)   Binary - The int32 is the number of bytes in the (byte*).
subtype ::=   "\x00"  Generic binary subtype
  |   "\x01"  Function
  |   "\x02"  Binary (Old)
  |   "\x03"  UUID (Old)
  |   "\x04"  UUID
  |   "\x05"  MD5
  |   "\x80"  User defined
```

Similar question on this thread

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-dev/browse_thread/thread/1965aa234aa3ef1e

Comment: Interesting. Are those subtypes used for anything?

Comment: I guess so :-). The best place for ask is the BSON group. Definetely, there is a reason for the difference between the new `\x00` and the historical `\x02` (http://groups.google.com/group/bson/browse_thread/thread/c45f78fba9311975). For UUID and MD5 (my opinion) is for optimisation. Both are fixed length hexadecimal ( 16-byte/128-bit/32 hexadecimal digits, layout bit different UUID has `-`) and widely used, driver implementors could optimise the read/write.

Comment: I don't know what a driver could optimize here. All of the binary types are stored as `length(int32) subtype-byte bytes*`. Fixed length or not, the length is stored. And data is stored as raw bytes (not hexadecimals). Maybe an option for data validation? Or for display purposes: UUID could be displayed nicer than `BinData(3,........)`?

Comment: The initial link here no longer discusses BinData at all.  Even this link does not define what the values mean, but it does document Mongo's agreement with the BSON spec: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Answer (score 8):

Macrolinux is right but you have to be careful with his example as it will work but by accident.

The first argument to BinData() is the BSON binary subtype which, as has been mentioned is one of the following:

```
generic:  \x00 (0)
function: \x01 (1)
old:      \x02 (2)
uuid_old: \x03 (3)
uuid:     \x04 (4)
md5:      \x05 (5)
user:     \x80 (128)
```

These are just helpers so that the deserializer can interpret the binary data differently depending on what those bytes represent **except** for the subtype 2 which is like the generic subtype but stores an int32 representing the length of the byte array as the first 4 bytes of data.

Now to see why the example is wrong you'll note that calling BinData(2, "1234") doesn't store the binary representing the string "1234" for two reasons:

- The BinData function interprets that string as a base64 encoded string.
- Type 2 would require that the first 4 bytes be an int32 containing the length of the byte array.

See bsonspec.org for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* they they correspond to the [BSON subtypes](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification):

> subtype   ::= "\x00"  Binary / Generic
>       |   "\x01"  Function
>       |   "\x02"  Binary (Old)
>       |   "\x03"  UUID
>       |   "\x05"  MD5
>       |   "\x80"  User defined

Looking at that, it appears that `0` is almost always a valid choice.